Restoring an optimizer state across multiple devices in JAX
I'm training a model using jax and optax on four GPUs and need to save and restore the optimizer state, but I'm running into a problem loading it. The optimizer state is initialized --
optimizer = optax.adamw(0.0001)
class Runner():
    self.opt_state = optimizer.init(self.params) # intialize the optimizer
    self.opt_state = jax.device_put_replicated(self.opt_state, devices) # replicate the opt_state to all devices

then saved only on the first device --
def save(self, save_dir):
    params_path = save_dir + '/{}_params.pickle'.format(self.train_step)
    opt_state_path = save_dir + '/{}_opt_state.pickle'.format(self.train_step)

    with open(params_path, 'wb') as file:
      pickle.dump(jax.device_get(jax.tree_map(lambda x: x[0], self.params)), file)
    with open(opt_state_path, 'wb') as file:
      pickle.dump(jax.device_get(jax.tree_map(lambda x: x[0], self.opt_state)), file)
    
    logging.info('saved to {}, step {}'.format(save_dir, self.train_step))

Later on, the parameters and optimizer state are loaded
def restore(self, save_dir, step, restore_opt_state = True):
    opt_state_path = save_dir + '/{}_opt_state.pickle'.format(step)
    if restore_opt_state: # True
      with open(opt_state_path, 'rb') as file:
        opt_state = pickle.load(file)
        replicate_opt_state = jax.device_put_replicated(opt_state, self.devices) # replicate the opt_state to all devices
        self.opt_state = update_dict(self.opt_state, replicate_opt_state)
      logging.info('restored opt state from {}, step {}'.format(save_dir, step))

where update_dict() is defined:
def update_dict(params1, params2):
  assert type(params1) == type(params2)
  if type(params1) == dict:
    params1.update(params2)
  elif type(params1) == FrozenDict:
    p = dict(params1['params'])
    p.update(params2['params'])
    params1 = {'params': FrozenDict(p)}
  else:
    raise ValueError('params1 type {} not implemented'.format(type(params1)))
  return params1

When I run the restore method on the correct save_dir and step, though, update_dict() interprets it as a tuple and cannot restore the optimizer state (ValueError: params1 type <class 'tuple'> not implemented). I'm not sure why this is, though, since save() explicitly saves only the optimizer state on the first device. Additionally, this same setup seems to work find when loading the parameters from a single device and replicating them across multiple devices.
I was expecting similar performance to params, which gets saved and loaded as a dictionary. I've tried explicitly adding another jax.tree_map(lambda x: x[0] opt_state) to the restore_opt_state context manager, which didn't work. It also looks like opt_state is being saved as a tuple, not as a dictionary, which is what params is being saved as. Would it be enough to pass one of the elements of the tuple through update_dict()?

I'd suggest editing your code to add a minimal reproducible example demonstrating the error you're seeing. As written this question is very hard to answer because it's unclear what code you're actually running (for example your Runner definition is invalid due to undefined variables).
